# How to get the nth string in any generic word or sentence with a space delimiter

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How do I get the nth word in a sentence or a set of strings with space delimiter?

Sorry for the change in the requirement.Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using [`instr`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php).

```
select substr(help, 1, instr(help,' ') - 1)
  from ( select 'hello my name is...' as help
           from dual )
```

`instr(help,' ')` returns the positional index of the first occurrence of the second argument in the first, inclusive of the string you're searching for. i.e. the first occurrence of `' '` in the string `'hello my name is...'` *plus* the space.

`substr(help, 1, instr(help,' ') - 1)` then takes the input string from the first character to the index indicated in `instr(...`. I then remove one so that the space isn't included..

---

For the nth occurrence just change this slightly:

`instr(help,' ',1,n)` is the *nth* occurrence of `' '` from the first character. You then need to find the positional index of the next index `instr(help,' ',1,n + 1)`, lastly work out the difference between them so you know how far to go in your `substr(...`. As you're looking for the *nth*, when *n* is 1 this breaks down and you have to deal with it, like so:

```
select substr( help
             , decode( n
                     , 1, 1
                     , instr(help, ' ', 1, n - 1) + 1
                       )
             , decode( &1
                     , 1, instr(help, ' ', 1, n ) - 1
                     , instr(help, ' ', 1, n) - instr(help, ' ', 1, n - 1) - 1
                       )
               )
  from ( select 'hello my name is...' as help
           from dual )
```

This will also break down at *n*. As you can see this is getting ridiculous so you might want to consider using [`regular expressions`](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html)

```
select regexp_substr(help, '[^[:space:]]+', 1, n )
  from ( select 'hello my name is...' as help
           from dual )
```

Comment: Atleast tell me how do I get the count of words in a string using space delimiter.

Comment: @Vutukuri, that is unfair, you changed the question. You can't expect answers to update themselves. I've given a lot of information in my update, that should all help you find the count - though it answers the question as well. The last link is probably the best for  this, see: `regexp_count`.

Comment: +1 You've earned it (and your regular expression solution is a bit better than mine.

Answer (score 5):

Try this.  An example of getting the 4th word:

```
select names from (
    select 
        regexp_substr('I want my two dollars','[^ ]+', 1, level) as names,
        rownum as nth
    from dual
    connect by regexp_substr('I want my two dollars', '[^ ]+', 1, level) is not null
)
where nth = 4;
```

The inner query is converting the space-delimited string into a set of rows.  The outer query is grabbing the nth item from the set.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
WITH q AS (SELECT 'ABCD EFGH IJKL' AS A_STRING FROM DUAL)
  SELECT SUBSTR(A_STRING, 1, INSTR(A_STRING, ' ')-1)
    FROM q
```

Share and enjoy.

---

And here's the solution for the revised question:

```
WITH q AS (SELECT 'ABCD EFGH IJKL' AS A_STRING, 3 AS OCCURRENCE FROM DUAL)
  SELECT SUBSTR(A_STRING,
                CASE
                  WHEN OCCURRENCE=1 THEN 1
                  ELSE INSTR(A_STRING, ' ', 1, OCCURRENCE-1)+1
                END,
                CASE
                  WHEN INSTR(A_STRING, ' ', 1, OCCURRENCE) = 0 THEN LENGTH(A_STRING)
                  ELSE INSTR(A_STRING, ' ', 1, OCCURRENCE) - CASE
                                                               WHEN OCCURRENCE=1 THEN 0
                                                               ELSE INSTR(A_STRING, ' ', 1, OCCURRENCE-1)
                                                             END - 1
                END)
    FROM q;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Answer rewritten to match the revised question.  Change OCCURRENCE in the factoring clause to match the substring/word you're trying to locate.  Answer similar to @Ben's, but I prefer CASE expressions.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROC spGetCharactersInAStrings
(
    @S VARCHAR(100) = '^1402 WSN NI^AMLAB^tev^e^^rtS htimS 0055518',
    @Char VARCHAR(100) = '8'
)
AS
-- exec spGetCharactersInAStrings '^1402 WSN NI^AMLAB^tev^e^^rtS htimS 0055518', '5'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i INT = 1,
            @c INT,
            @pos INT = 0,
            @NewStr VARCHAR(100),
            @sql NVARCHAR(100),
            @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500) = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT'

```
DECLARE @D TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    String VARCHAR(100),
    Position INT
)

SELECT @c = LEN(@S), @NewStr = @S

WHILE @i <= @c
BEGIN
    SET @sql = ''
    SET @sql = ' SELECT @retvalOUT = CHARINDEX(''' +  + @Char + ''',''' + @NewStr + ''')'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @ParmDefinition, @retvalOUT=@i OUTPUT;

    IF @i > 0
    BEGIN
        set @pos = @pos + @i
        SELECT @NewStr = SUBSTRING(@NewStr, @i + 1, LEN(@S))
        --SELECT @NewStr '@NewStr', @Char '@Char', @pos '@pos', @sql '@sql'
        --SELECT @NewStr '@NewStr', @pos '@pos'

        INSERT INTO @D
            SELECT @NewStr, @pos

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
    ELSE
        BREAK
END
SELECT * FROM @D
```

END

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL and cannot use the instr function that accepts four parameters or regexp_substr, you can do this way:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(help, ' ', 2), ' ', -1)
from (select 'hello my name is...' as help) h
```

Result: "my".

Replace "2" in the code above with the number of the word you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016+ then you can take advantage of the STRING_SPLIT function. It returns rows of string values and if you aim to get nth value, then you can use Row_Number() window function.

Here there is a little trick as you don't want to really order by something so that you have to "cheat" the row_number function and allow its value in the natural order which is the STRING_SPLIT() function will spit out.

Below is a code snippet if you want to find the third word of the string

```
Declare @_intPart INT = 3; -- change nth work here, start # from 1 not 0 
SELECT value FROM(
    SELECT  value, 
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rowno
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('hello world this is amazing', ' ')
) AS o1 WHERE o1.rowno = @_intPart;
```

You can also make a scalar function to retrieve values.