# Oracle Query to select only the text between two '-' characters

Tags: oracle, plsql, character

I would like to replace a column values selecting only the text inside the two '-' character. Example: `Case 1 - Deleted - The case is closed`.

So, i would like something like this:

*Original:*

```
Description
------------------------------------------
Case 1 - Deleted - The case is closed
```

*What I want to have:*

```
Description
------------------------------------------
Deleted
```

I have this but i dont know how to delete the text after the second '-' and replace that result on the current column **Description**

```
select SUBSTR(description, INSTR(description, '-') + 1) left_value
from (
    select description
    from all_cases
    );
```

Comment: What if text looks like: `Case 1 - Deleted1 - The case is closed - Deleted2 - bla`. Then what is expected result ?

Comment: No. The specific format for the text is: Case # - Reason - Bla Bla.

Comment: Other option is to remove the text after and before the '-'. (but  i dont know how to to that)

Comment: There are a lot of answers for "how to get the nth word in a delimited string", for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109335/how-to-get-the-nth-string-in-any-generic-word-or-sentence-with-a-space-delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since INSTR function allows to set what occurrence of any character you want, you can use this to identify the pieces to erase based on the "-" character:

```
select  trim(
            replace(  
                    replace(
                                description, 
                                SUBSTR(description, 1, INSTR(description, '-',1,1)), -- <-- first occurrence of "-"
                                null), 
                    SUBSTR(description, INSTR(description, '-',1,2), -- <-- second occurrence of "-"
                    length(description)), 
                    null)
        ) as result
from all_cases;
```

Assuming that all your rows follow the same pattern, update all in one call would look something like this:

```
update all_cases
set description = trim(
                    replace(  
                        replace(description, 
                                SUBSTR(description, 1, INSTR(description, '-',1,1)),
                                null), 
                        SUBSTR(description, INSTR(description, '-',1,2), length(description)), 
                        null)
                    );
```

Which acts just identifying the left and right pieces based in the "-" character and replacing them with null.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way:

```
with t(col) as(
select 'Case # - Reason - Bla Bla' from dual union all
select 'Case # - Reason2 - Bla Bla' from dual 
)

select 
substr( 
    col, 
    INSTR (col , '-' , 1, 1)+1,  
    INSTR (col , '-' , 1, 2) - INSTR (col , '-' , 1, 1) - 1
)
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SQL>  variable s1 varchar2(40)
SQL> exec :s1:='Case 1 - Deleted1 - The case is closed';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select substr(:s1,instr(:s1,'-')+1,instr(:s1,'-',2)+1) substr_value from dual;

SUBSTR_VALUE
------------------------------
 Deleted1
```

Comment: the position of the character is not the same.

Comment: The business about the third argument and how it works with a negative value was incorrect, so I edited my answer and removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid all that fugly nested substr/instr with REGEXP_SUBSTR():

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
     select 'Case 1 - Deleted - The case is closed' from dual
   )
   select trim(regexp_substr(str, '-(.*)-', 1, 1, null, 1)) fixed
   from tbl;

FIXED
-------
Deleted
```

Edit: Changed to simplify regex and allow for cases where there may not be spaces inside of the dashes.